# Git push - could not resolve host

Tags: git, github

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true

$ git push -u origin main
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Habeeb690/usd.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are using proxy and that messes it up. It may help:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```